# Comparing two values from Dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Dropdown from which I pass the Name value OnClick

```
onClick={() => clicked(v.Name)
```

Then, in the clicked event I want to compare that the input value is not the same as old value but this fails because I cannot update oldName after comparing the values. Probably there is a better logic to this. I also tried UseEffect and UseState but they tended to update with previous values.

function DropdownComponent() {

```
    var oldName;

    function clicked(Name) {
        if (Name === oldName) {
            console.log("Same Clicked!");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Differet Clicked!");
            setTitleName(Name)
        } return oldName = (Name); //can't update
    }

    return (
    <Dropdown //dropdown component

}
```

Comment: Hi David,
Thanks for valid comments. You are correct with my error. The thing is, when I compare with titleName, this works, but only after I click the same value three times, so the oldName updates late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything stored in a component-local variable only exists for that render.  Each render will re-declare the variable.  So this variable:

```
var oldName;
```

Will *always* be `undefined` on every render.  Component-local variables can be useful for temporary storage.  For example, you can perform sorting/filtering logic on an array and store the results in variables for the purpose of mapping those variable to UI components in the render, effectively separate the sorting/filtering logic from the rendering logic.

But those variable *do not persist* across renders.

If you want something to be retained across renders, you want to keep it in state.  Which you *appear* to already be doing here:

```
setTitleName(Name)
```

The code shown doesn't include this, but *presumably* somewhere you're creating a state value like this?:

```
const [titleName, setTitleName] = useState('');
```

If we are to assume that this "title name" is a state value then you already have the "previous value", it's the one you're keeping in state.  So just check against that one:

```
function clicked(name) {
    if (name === titleName) {
        console.log("Same Clicked!");
    } else {
        console.log("Differet Clicked!");
        setTitleName(name);
    }
}
```

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-leftpad-sepuly?file=/src/App.js)